# Can I debug an wp8 app on a windows 10 device using visual studio 2013?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

Actually I am trying to do this, but I get the following error code: 0x89731B01. If I use a wp8 device it works.

Comment: 0x89731B01 means that a device was found, but the remote debugger/deployment service isn't responding to a request. Reboot your device and XAP deployment should work. [Source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64574748&postcount=360) so try to reboot the phone. Also make sure you use latest Win10 mobile build 14393.1066

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am using windows phone 8 SDK, because the app installed on the de windows 10 device is developed used wp8 SDK

Comment: and? have you done the reboot? also try http://wptools.codeplex.com/ to deploy apps

Comment: I have solved my problem installing Visual Studio 2015

Comment: ok, post this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to install Visual Studio 2015 in order to make the debugging